# Describe the SVN symbols

Tags: svn

Can some describe and help me understand **all** the svn symbols, like `A`, `M` , `G` , `?` and `>` ?

Comment: Type svn status into websearch and the first hit is this: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re26.html

Comment: For result codes, also see [What do the result codes in SVN mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2034/6338809)

Answer (score 100):

All those codes are explained by the `svn help status` command, which throws:

```
 The first seven columns in the output are each one character wide:
First column: Says if item was added, deleted, or otherwise changed
  ' ' no modifications
  'A' Added
  'C' Conflicted
  'D' Deleted
  'I' Ignored
  'M' Modified
  'R' Replaced
  'X' an unversioned directory created by an externals definition
  '?' item is not under version control
  '!' item is missing (removed by non-svn command) or incomplete
  '~' versioned item obstructed by some item of a different kind
Second column: Modifications of a file's or directory's properties
  ' ' no modifications
  'C' Conflicted
  'M' Modified
Third column: Whether the working copy directory is locked
  ' ' not locked
  'L' locked
Fourth column: Scheduled commit will contain addition-with-history
  ' ' no history scheduled with commit
  '+' history scheduled with commit
Fifth column: Whether the item is switched or a file external
  ' ' normal
  'S' the item has a Switched URL relative to the parent
  'X' a versioned file created by an eXternals definition
Sixth column: Repository lock token
  (without -u)
  ' ' no lock token
  'K' lock token present
  (with -u)
  ' ' not locked in repository, no lock token
  'K' locked in repository, lock toKen present
  'O' locked in repository, lock token in some Other working copy
  'T' locked in repository, lock token present but sTolen
  'B' not locked in repository, lock token present but Broken
Seventh column: Whether the item is the victim of a tree conflict
  ' ' normal
  'C' tree-Conflicted
```

A very userful [Cheat sheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/subversion-cheat-sheet/) to manage all svn commands.

Comment: This information, with a little more explanatory text, is also available at [the free online Subversion reference](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html).

Comment: What is the 'E' code mean during a check-out with the --force option?  (I think it means "existing", but I'm not certain.)

Comment: E = File existed before the update; Anyway, I recommend to migrate to GIT from SVN, it works a thousand of times better

Comment: `G: Changes on the repo were automatically merged into the working copy`

Answer (score 35):

`svn help status` will give you a full legend with all the information you need.  Since self help isn't an option and suggesting such things is frowned upon, below is the legend I got when I ran `svn help status` using Subversion 1.7.5:

```
  The first seven columns in the output are each one character wide:
    First column: Says if item was added, deleted, or otherwise changed
      ' ' no modifications
      'A' Added
      'C' Conflicted
      'D' Deleted
      'I' Ignored
      'M' Modified
      'R' Replaced
      'X' an unversioned directory created by an externals definition
      '?' item is not under version control
      '!' item is missing (removed by non-svn command) or incomplete
      '~' versioned item obstructed by some item of a different kind
    Second column: Modifications of a file's or directory's properties
      ' ' no modifications
      'C' Conflicted
      'M' Modified
    Third column: Whether the working copy directory is locked
      ' ' not locked
      'L' locked
    Fourth column: Scheduled commit will contain addition-with-history
      ' ' no history scheduled with commit
      '+' history scheduled with commit
    Fifth column: Whether the item is switched or a file external
      ' ' normal
      'S' the item has a Switched URL relative to the parent
      'X' a versioned file created by an eXternals definition
    Sixth column: Repository lock token
      (without -u)
      ' ' no lock token
      'K' lock token present
      (with -u)
      ' ' not locked in repository, no lock token
      'K' locked in repository, lock toKen present
      'O' locked in repository, lock token in some Other working copy
      'T' locked in repository, lock token present but sTolen
      'B' not locked in repository, lock token present but Broken
    Seventh column: Whether the item is the victim of a tree conflict
      ' ' normal
      'C' tree-Conflicted
    If the item is a tree conflict victim, an additional line is printed
    after the item's status line, explaining the nature of the conflict.
```

I hope you realize that `svn help status` is Subversion version specific which means this answer and the one credited as the correct answer might or might not be correct based on your Subversion version where as running `svn help status` will always be accurate.