# What does it mean when SVN indents a status code by one extra space?

Tags: svn, subclipse

I just did a plain old SVN update through Subclipse, and this came up in my SVN console:

```
update C:/project/ -r HEAD --force
    U   C:/project/.project
    D   C:/project/mroozek
     U  C:/project/timeStone
     U  C:/project/barchern
    U   C:/project/lorem.java
    A   C:/project/ipsum.java
```

<sup>*The filenames are made up, but the types are correct.*</sup>
Why is the status code (U, in the example) indented by one extra space on some lines?

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034/what-do-the-result-codes-in-svn-mean/12813#12813), which links to [this reference page](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html) about SVN's `status` command. Not _exactly_ the same as the result of updating, but fairly similar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first column says if the file was added, deleted, or otherwise changed.

The second column shows the modifications of a file's or directory's properties.

So in your case the contents of the 2 files mentioned remained unchanged, while their properties changed in some way.