# How to resolve SVN status code "~"?

Tags: wordpress, svn

It's been a while that I use SVN, but now that I'm starting to learn wordpress, and upgraded a plugin inside Wordpress, my `svn status` returned something like this:

```
~       wp-content/plugins/captcha
```

I've read ([What do the result codes in SVN mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034/what-do-the-result-codes-in-svn-mean)) that this status means that the object changed its type, like if it was a file and now it's a folder, and that's not what happened.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved!

The problem was that Wordpress removed the `.svn` folder from this plugin folder. Then I removed it from the versioning system with `svn rm wp-content/plugins/captcha --keep-local` and putting it again, with `svn add wp-content/plugins/captcha`.

Comment: Nice. This was really helpful in solving this status code. Thanks!

Comment: As a side note, this occurs a lot when deleting folders/files via a task runner like Gulp. What's a good approach to avoid this? In case any Grunt/Gulp/etc. users come across this comment.

Comment: @ConAntonakos Maybe you should remove generated files from the versioning system, or use the `file.extension.dist` pattern...