# SVN - Commit doesn't recognize files inside new folder

Tags: svn, svn-merge, svn-reintegrate, svn-merge-reintegrate

**Environment:**

**OS:** Linux Mint 14

**SVN**: 1.8.3

This issue occurs under command line and subclipse plugin.

I create a new java package under an existing project, and adding many classes in this package. When I commited into the branch, everything is ok.
But, when I try to merge a branch into trunk, a.k.a reintegrate (don't using the --reintegrate option, it's deprecated in svn 1.8) anything wrong happened and there aren't conflict reports. Merge bring all modifications, including the new package and their files.

When I tried to commit or check for modifications (svn status), only package was shown. The files seemed like versioned, and in last revision of my repo. This fact occurs in other branches too. Every commit that includes new package has a problem to merge in working copy.

It's interesting, because when I merge the branch revision by revision, it works. It seems the problem are related with the automerge.

Comment: Can you provide a simple example preferably starting with `svnadmin create` showing all the svn commands you use and the output of the commands ending with the issue you're seeing.  It'll be much easier to understand the problem this way.  There are a lot of different things you can be doing with the way you described the issue.

Comment: @BenReser The best description I can give to you is:
After an auto-merge using command: "svn merge ^/repo" in working copy,  results in this result: folder is shown with "A+", but content are shown only with "+".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If when you run the command `svn status` shows something like this:

```
M   .
A   + your_new_directory
```

.. you could ran with `--verbose` option to see more details. Now, the output may look like this:

```
M    rev0 rev1 author  .
A +     - rev1 you     your_new_directory
  +     - rev1 you     your_new_directory/your_file
```

You can see more status related stuff on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034/what-do-the-result-codes-in-svn-mean).

So, probably your files are there, but the non-verbose status from svn isn't showing.