# What does mean by ↓ and C besides file name in Xcode9 Project Navigator?

Tags: xcode

> I know about M, A, U, ?, R, I.

I searched for the `↓` and `C`  but not found any helpful resources.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28196429/xcode-repository-indicators-meanings) post doesn't contain info about `↓`.

Can anyone tell me what indicates these symbols?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it is an arrow and not the `!` symbol?

Comment: Yes, it's a down arrow not !

Comment: Can you post relevant portion of a screenshot showing some files with the arrow?

Comment: After pushing on git this arrow has been gone but whenever this arrow will be there I will attach screenshot thank you so much for understanding. I am using Xcode 9.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`C` means [conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4920885/957768) — you tried to merge (or implicitly merge due to a pull) a branch where, in the marked file, git can't automatically resolve the differences between your working copy and the other branch. You'll need to use Xcode's version editor or an external tool to manually decide which changes from each side to keep, then tell git that the conflicts are resolved (IIRC in Xcode you can do this by right-clicking on the file in the navigator).

`↓` means your working copy is "behind" the other branch by some number of commits (in this case, because the conflict meant it couldn't catch up).

Answer (score 1):

Down arrow indicated that your local working directory has changes.
C means conflict your local file and remote file has changes in same places.