# SVN switch - What does the output mean?

Tags: svn, version-control, pycharm

When I switch branches using `svn switch` command, I get an output similar to this:

```
D address/repo/
A address/repo/dir_1
A address/repo/dir_2
...
A address/repo/dir_n/.../dir_m
```

I assume D stands for delete and A stands for add.

Can someone explain exactly what is deleted and added?

I am using PyCharm but I issue the command from the terminal. In PyCharm, after a branch switch, I have to do VCS - Refresh File Status after every switch. Why is that?

Thanks!

**EDIT 1:**

So, from  what I understand, if I am on branch_1 and I do `svn switch branch_2` what happens is SVN deletes stuff from branch_1 that is not in branch_2, adds stuff that is in branch_2 but not in branch_1 and updates things that are common to the two branches, to fit the branch_2 revision.

Comment: What's added and deleted? The files that don't exist in both branches thus need to be added or deleted to reflect the repository code in your local copy.

Comment: Everything is deleted and added again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do the result codes in SVN mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034/what-do-the-result-codes-in-svn-mean)

Comment: It's maybe not obvious, but it's the same codes as for `svn status` with a few extras, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2036/4498329