# Subclipse update results

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I'm a little new to Subclipse and just did an update on the whole project. Subclipse nicely produced the following output in the Eclipse Console window. (Never got anything like this with Subversive.) so I can guess that the A in the first column (and highlighted in yellow) indicates the file was an addition to the repository since my last update. And that the U indicates the file has been updated with no conflicts. But what does the G mean? I'm guessing it must be something important cuz it's red.

[image]

I found the nice list of icons on [StackOverflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917925/what-do-the-arrow-icons-in-subclipse-mean/3920248#3920248) but this is not icons. I'm asking about the output from the Update command.

Comment: You did read the "merged: 2" line?

Comment: Yes, and I could assume that the Merged and the G were related, but I didn't want to make any assumptions. Also if they were merged should I see something about that in the Team Synchronizing view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are standard svn update command statuses. `G` means automatically merged. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2036/639520) for more details.

Comment: Thank-you for the link. That's what I was looking for. Didn't realize it was an SVN detail. Also, if those files were merged does that appear in the Team Synchronization perspective in Eclipse?

Comment: Ok, I answered the Team Synchronization question myself. Yes, it does, it was just hard to find, under the Outgoing view.