# Swift files in Xcode have Question Mark (?)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am working with Xcode for 3 months now. This has happened to me twice.

Xcode deleted my `ViewController.swift` file twice. I couldn't find it in the bin. I dont know whats wrong with that.

App was working nice then I commit my code. After that, Xcode gives me compile error:

> File "myController.swift" not found

Xcode showing "?" at front of my swift file:

[image]

Comment: The question mark means that a file has not yet been added to Source Control if I'm correct.

Comment: i can try this one as well can you please guide me how i can add ?

Comment: @lennartk thanks to you.. you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question mark means that the file is not under version control, it doesn't mean that it has been deleted. You can use the command `git add -A` to add all files in the directory to your version control. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034/what-do-the-result-codes-in-svn-mean) lists all the Xcode version control symbols, here they are.

> U: Working file was updated
>
> G: Changes on the repo were automatically merged into the working copy
>
> M: Working copy is modified
>
> C: This file conflicts with the version in the repo
>
> ?: This file is not under version control
>
> !: This file is under version control but is missing or incomplete
>
> A: This file will be added to version control (after commit)
>
> A+: This file will be moved (after commit)
>
> D: This file will be deleted (after commit)
>
> S: This signifies that the file or directory has been switched from the path of the rest of the working copy (using svn switch) to a branch
>
> I: Ignored
>
> X: External definition
>
> ~: Type changed
>
> R: Item has been replaced in your working copy. This means the file was scheduled for deletion, and then a new file with the same name was scheduled for addition in its place.
>
> L : Item is locked
>
> E: Item existed, as it would have been created, by an svn update.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the git/source tree when your code is under version control. when you import files to your project and this will not be added in git.

To fix this:

right-click on the '?' file and select source control then at the bottom click **Add Selected Files**. This should fix.[image]